# Backbone findWhere finds nothing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My collection has 4494 models. I try to use findWhere to get specific model by id. The findWhere returns 'undefined'.

It works ok if I limit the number of models. The strangeness heppens when the number of models is over 100.

```
var users = this.usersCollection;

console.log(users);
```

> [image: console screen]

```
console.log(users.findWhere({uid: 1}));
```

> [image: collection screen]

Comment: If your collection is that large, I suggest that you use an index to lookup your objects instead of a `find` in the first place. Still, the behaviour is weird…

Comment: Seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/r1Ljx6fg/

Comment: Yes, it works. Strange. I can see in the collection that each 100 models are wrapped with an array. In ur example there is nothing like that. What is wrong with my collection? I attached a screen

Comment: All I can say is that your models are incorrectly added to your collection. Without seeing how you do that, not much I can add.

Comment: @OlegBrynzovskii *"each 100 models are wrapped with an array"* - it's just how chrome dev tools displays large amount of data (otherwise imagine the scroll). It's not the structure of your actual data.

Comment: You might be using `findWhere` before the collection is actually fetched. And you might be opening the collection object in console after it's fetched. This is the most likely scenario. If it doesn't help share [mcve]

Comment: @TJ thank you, u were right about using findWhere before the collection is actually fetched. Thank you for support. And for the future will use mcve  as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to use my collection before it was completely fetched.

Answer (score 0):

While the problem is solved (*using `findWhere` before the collection is actually fetched*) thanks to [TJ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134018/backbone-findwhere-finds-nothing#comment71436199_42134018), you might want to use [`.get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) instead of `findWhere` when searching a model by id.

If your `User` model looks something like this:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'uid',
    // ...
});
```

You could get a user by id from the collection directly:

```
var user = users.get(1);
```

You can also use `get` with the model's `cid` or the model instance.

```
user === users.get(user.cid)
user === users.get(user)
```

This is better because Backbone keeps a hash of the models with the specified id attribute as the key in addition of the usual array.

Comment: Good advice, I ll keep it in mind next time, Thank you!